# FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in log TransformedTargetRegressor

Tags: python

I am trying to build a TransformedTargetRegressor in this way:

```
 rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = random_state ,n_estimators=RF_n_estimators, n_jobs= RF_n_jobs ,criterion = RF_Regression_criterion ,min_samples_split = RF_min_samples_split ,max_features = RF_max_features )
model=TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=rf,func=np.log, inverse_func=np.exp)
```

However, I get this error:

```
FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in log
```

I dont get why I get this error when I try to work with this model? and what can I do to solve this issues?

Also, what type of transformation can I use to get a normal distrubtion of the data given that the target data has negative values?

Answer (score 0):

Check your data for containing 0's in the target. The `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log` is encountered when you compute `np.log(0)` which your `TransformedTargetRegressor` is doing. It is transforming the output variable by the `log`. Either remove the 0s from the target (ensuring it is strictly positive) or don't use this log transformation.

In general for regression problems, transformations are to make the target variable as close to normal as possible. A log transform works well for strictly positive values with large outliers (it transforms large values more than small values). If outliers are not a problem you could use other transformations (subtract mean and divide by std for example).

You should plot histograms and try a few options and select the best. There is no silver bullet to transform any distribution to look like a gaussian.

Comment: But when we type np.log(0) it gives us -inf why after putting it into the regressor gives us the error?
Also, what type of transformation can I use to get a normal distrubtion of the data given that the data has negative values?

Comment: You'd have to dig into the scikit learn code to determine where it throws the error but if you are minimising a loss function (e.g., distance to a target) and a term is `inf` then this dominates your loss and you can't minimise the signal. So it seems natural to me to throw an error here.